# Eliminar un elemento de JSON

Tags: python, mongodb, update

mi pregunta es: ¿cómo puedo eliminar un elemento de un array dentro de un JSON?
Las tecnologías utilizadas son **python** y **mongodb** (**pymongo**)
Un poco confuso, pero os dejo el código y os explico que quiero hacer:

```
@app.route('/delete/<id>/<id_to_delete>', methods=['PUT'])
def delete_conn(id, id_to_delete):
    #Busco el usuario de la sesion
    data = mongo.db.users.update(
        {'_id': ObjectId(id)},
        {'$set':{
            'conn': [] <-- Aqui quiero modificar
        }}
    )
    user = json_util.dumps(data)
    #Elimino el usuario en cuestión
    print(data)
    return "1"
```

Mi intención es encontrar el usuario y modificar el listado 'conn' asociado a el. Los datos que tengo en la BD son del tipo:
{'_id:x,
'name':y,
'conn': ["a","b",...]}. Suponiendo que este es el usuario encontrado y quiero eliminar el elemento "a" dentro de la lista 'conn', ¿cómo lo podría hacer?

Comment: Hola IRetro, si lo que deseas eliminar es un elemento de la lista, tienes dos opciones para eliminar, el uso de pop y remove. Para pop necesitas el índice, por ejemplo en tu caso conn.pop(0) y con remove accedes con el valor, eliminando el primer elemento de la lista que encuentre con ese valor. Por ejemplo, conn.remove("a"). Pero tendrías que acceder al dato de tu objeto. Sería desde user entiendo.
https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: ¿Quieres modificar desde el `update` de mongo? lo menciono porque eso es lo que indicas en el código, o quieres modificar el resultado que esta en `data` sin modificar nada en mongo, saludos

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es eliminar un elemento de 'conn', usando el id del usuario. Basicamente en conn almaceno el 'id' y el 'name' de los usuarios que tienen conexion con el usuario de la sesion, y lo que quiero hacer es eliminar la conexion

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea actualizar un documento de [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com) eliminando un valor de un campo de tipo `Array`. Para ello se desea usar el método [`update`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update), sin embargo, el mismo ha sido marcado como *obsoleto* y se sugiere el uso de [`update_one`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Usaremos el método `update_one` tal como sugiere la documentación de [`pymongo`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/), y nos apoyaremos en el operador [`$pullAll`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/#up._S_pullAll) de MongoDB para realizar la actualización sobre el campo de tipo `Array` en el documento.

```py
data = mongo.db.users.update_one( # <- usamos update_one
    {'_id': ObjectId(id)},
    {'$pullAll':
      {
        'conn': ["a"] # <- remueve todas las apariciones de "a"
      }
    }
)
```

De esta forma, estarás modificando correctamente el campo `conn` de tipo `Array`, eliminando todas las coincidencias pasadas en la lista: `["a"]`.

Si deseas eliminar más de un elemento, basta agregarlos a la lista: `["a", "b", ...]`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

En otra pregunta (que sugerí eliminaras por ser un duplicado de esta) dices que tienes la siguiente estructura:

```js
_id: ObjectId(...)
name: x
conn: [{_id: ObjectId(a), name: b},{_id: ObjectId(c), name: d}, ...]
```

Como el campo `conn` es un `Array` de documentos del tipo:

```js
[
  {_id: ObjectId(a), name: b},
  {_id: ObjectId(c), name: d},
  ...
]
```

Entonces el operador $pullAll no estaría bien implementado. Lo que debes hacer es usar el operador [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/), específicamente la forma de realizar la [actualización del campo tipo `Array` cuyos elementos son documentos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull-array-of-documents).

La consulta de actualización quedaría:

```py
data = mongo.db.users.update_one( # <- usamos update_one
  {'_id': ObjectId(id)},
  {'$pull':
    {
      'conn': { '_id': ObjectId(id_a_eliminar) }
    }
  }
)
```

En tu planteamiento posterior en la otra pregunta, estabas usando [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch), lo cual no actualizaba correctamente el `Array`, esto debido a que `$elemMatch` hace una comparación sobre elementos de un `Array` dentro de un documento *embebido*. La cual no es la estructura de tu documento.

De la documentación se tiene: (traducción propia):

> Debido a que el operador `$pull` aplica su consulta a cada elemento como si se tratara de un objeto de nivel superior, la expresión no requiere el uso de `$elemMatch` para especificar la condición ...

**¿Cuándo usamos `$elemMatch`?**

Usaremos el operador `$elemMatch` cunado necesitamos actualizar un documento embebido (en un `Array` o en otro campo), basados en valores de un campo de tipo `Array` de dicho documento `embebido`.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tu documento tenga la siguiente estructura:

```js
_id: ObjectId(...),
name: x,
conn: [{_id: ObjectId(a), name: b, access: [{primary: true}, {secondary: false}]},{_id: ObjectId(c), name: d, access: [{primary: false}, {secondary: false}]}, ...]
```

Claramente la estructura de los documentos del campo de tipo `Array` llamado `conn` es la siguiente:

```js
[
  {_id: ObjectId(a), name: b, access: [{primary: true}, {secondary: false}]},
  {_id: ObjectId(c), name: d, access: [{primary: false}, {secondary: false}]},
  ...
]
```

Tenemos un campo llamado `access` que es de tipo `Array` en cada documento embebido dentro del campo `conn`.

En este caso para poder hacer *match* contra algún elemento del `Array` llamado `access`, necesitamos usar `$elemMatch`.

Por ejemplo, si deseo eliminar de `conn` todos los documentos que tengan el campo `_id` y un acceso de tipo `primary` establecido en `true`, la consulta sería:

```py
data = mongo.db.users.update_one( # <- usamos update_one
  {'_id': ObjectId(id)},
  {'$pull':
    {
      'conn': { # condiciones sobre el campo conn
        '_id': ObjectId(id_a_eliminar), # <- el campo _id
        'access': { # <- elementos de access que cumplan la condición
          '$elemMatch': {
            'primary': True
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Con esto espero quede aclarada la diferencia de usar `$pull` sobre documentos embebidos en un `Array` y usar `$pull` junto con `$elemMatch` cuando deseamos aplicar un *match* sobre elementos de un campo de tipo `Array` dentro del documento embebido.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estoy intentando hacerlo me está dando el siguiente error. Esto es lo que intento hacer:    update = mongo.db.users.update_one(
        {'_id':ObjectId(id)},
        {'$pullAll':
            {'conn': [{'_id': ObjectId(id_to_delete)}]}
        }
    ) y me da este error: pymongo.errors.WriteError: Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value.

Comment: Ese error indica que el campo llamado `conn` no es de tipo `Array`. ¿Estás seguro de que el documento que estás actualizando tiene un campo llamado `conn` y que el mismo es de tipo `Array`?

Comment: Si claro, podria ser que la sintaxis esta mal escrita?